# Calculate specific date given a day of week and instance of week in the month

Tags: date, math, salesforce, formula, apex

I have a situation where I need to calculate a specific day of the next upcoming month in a formula field, and the values I have to calculate this are:

-Day of week (M,T,W etc)
-Instance Week (2nd or 3rd week of the month)

I suggested an Apex solution where we would set a date variable for one month ahead, calculate the day of the week that the first of the month was, and loop through it until we got to our chosen "Day of week".  At that point we could add 7 days or 14 days to that value and that would give us what we need in terms of the second or third week of the month for a particular day.

The only problem is that there is about 2000 records that would need to be checked and updated nightly, and my company is uncomfortable leaving this up to a nightly job to go through and update this field.

I have been looking up equations that I could potentially setup in a formula field that will be able to show me the "Next Service Date" we will call it, and the formula field would be able to calculate this date anytime the page is viewed. (Or report exported for that matter).

I am totally stuck on a math equation that will use todays date to find the 2nd or 3rd instance of a specific day of the week in the following month.  I feel like from researching it is possible to do this with just an equation, but I am striking out.

Has anyone ever done anything like this before?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe what you are asking for is possible, but it will be easier if certain information is available. Are the day of the week, day of the month, month, and year available as separate variables? What programming language?

Comment: Edward-  I was hoping to accomplish this on the Force.com platform via their formula fields.  They have functions to return numerical values for the month and day, and I figure that the equation to figure this out will involve if statements that grab those date values.  Via the fields that exist, and the current date, I would say that all month and day options that would go into the calculation are available to be used.

Comment: Unfortunately, you also need to know the year so you can determine whether February has 28 days or 29 days. It also helps *immensely* if you know the day of week of the current day. (That can be figured out by another brutal formula, but it's much easier if the system provides it.)

Comment: I don't know anything about the Force.com platform but I can do it with purely mathematical calculations on any platform that has modulus/remainder (% in most languages I know) and integer division without remainder (/ where both operands are integers). In integer division, 3/2 = 1 not 1.5. Does the platform have those features?

Comment: Edward-- Thanks for your responses.  I do have the ability to round up or down, or to any closest number I specify.  It also has a MOD function that will return the remainder.   I also have the ability to grab the year.  Here is the reference I used to get your answers: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm

Comment: Floating point division plus floor is adequate as a replacement for integer division. MOD is adequate as a replacement for %, provided the result of MOD 7 is in the range 0 to 7 (I can't tell from the documentation, but I can't imagine it would be otherwise). The only piece missing is the current day of the week. However, that may be obtainable from DATEVALUE MOD 7. Please check that out.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `MOD(TODAY(),7)` may give the current day of the week. Is Sunday 0 or 1 or ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the calculation is not so hard using the language features described in the reference supplied in the comments to the question. To find the date value of the first day of the next month, use

```
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) + 1, 1)
```

To find the day of week of the first day of the next month, use

```
MOD( DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) + 1, 1) - DATE(1900,1,7), 7)
```

where Sun = 0, ... Sat = 6. To find the date of the first day_of_week next month, use

```
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())+1, 1)
+ day_of_week 
- MOD( DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())+1, 1) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 )
+
IF( 
  MOD(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1)-DATE(1900,1,7),7) >= day_of_week,
  7,
  0
)
```

Finally, to move to the 2nd or 3rd occurrence of the required day_of_week, use

```
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())+1, 1)
+ day_of_week 
- MOD( DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())+1, 1) - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 )
+
IF( 
  MOD(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,1)-DATE(1900,1,7),7) >= day_of_week,
  7,
  0
)
+ (occurrence - 1) * 7
```

This is easier than my pure math answer because the language has a built-in way to increment the month (`MONTH(TODAY())+1`).

Comment: This seemed to have worked for me.  Thank you so much!  Math amazes me sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, it is possible to find the nth occurrence of a given weekday using only mathematical formulas. Below I have included Java code to do the calculation step-by-step. The sequence of formulas can be reduced to one formula by substituting formulas into other formulas. I've output a lot of debugging information so I can keep an eye on the stages of the calculation. Note I have only tested the program lightly; it should be tested for wide array of inputs, including dates from 1995 to 2017.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class NextServiceDate {

  public static int // Jan = 1, Dec = 12, Sun = 1, Sat = 7
  nextServiceDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int dayOfWeek,
                  int targetDayOfWeek, int occurrenceOfDayOfWeek) {

    // We have to do all date calculations with mathematical formulas
    // all the formulas could be mashed together, if desired

    // Want March = 1, April = 2, May = 3, ..., January = 11, February = 12
    int monthMarchIs1 = (month+9)%12 + 1;
    System.out.println("Current month, where March is 1: " + monthMarchIs1);

    // want to know whether month is February
    int isMonthFeb = monthMarchIs1 / 12; // integer division
    System.out.println("Is month February: " + isMonthFeb);

    // want to know whether year is leap year
    // is year divisible by 4?
    int isYearDivBy4 = (1-(year%4+3)/4); // 0 = false, 1 = true
    System.out.println("Is year div by 4: " + isYearDivBy4);
    // is year divisible by 100?
    int isYearDivBy100 = (1-(year%100+99)/100);
    System.out.println("Is year div by 100: " + isYearDivBy100);
    // is year divisible by 400?
    int isYearDivBy400 = (1-(year%400+399)/400);
    System.out.println("Is year div by 400: " + isYearDivBy400);
    // Boolean logic to determine whether year is leap year
    // note year div by 400 implies year div by 100 so the result is never 2
    int isLeapYear = isYearDivBy4*(1-isYearDivBy100) + isYearDivBy400;
    System.out.println("Is year leap: " + isLeapYear);

    // calculate days in month using Curtis McEnroe's formula
    // http://cmcenroe.me/2014/12/05/days-in-month-formula.html
    // corrected for leap year using Boolean logic
    int daysInMonth = 28 + (month+month/8)%2 + 2%month + 2*(1/month)
      + isMonthFeb*isLeapYear;
    System.out.println("Days in month: " + daysInMonth);

    // number of days to the first of next month
    int daysToFirst = daysInMonth - dayOfMonth + 1;
    System.out.println("Days to the first of next month: " + daysToFirst);

    // weekday of first of next month
    int weekdayOfFirst = (dayOfWeek + daysToFirst) % 7; // Sat = 0
    System.out.println("Weekday of first of next month: " + weekdayOfFirst);

    // additional days to target day of week
    int dateOfTargetWeekday = (targetDayOfWeek-weekdayOfFirst+7)%7 + 1;
    System.out.println("Date of target day of week: " + dateOfTargetWeekday);

    // final answer: day of month of target date
    int dateOfTarget = dateOfTargetWeekday + (occurrenceOfDayOfWeek-1)*7;
    System.out.println("Day of month of target date: " + dateOfTarget);
    System.out.println();

    return dateOfTarget;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String[] MONTHABBR = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                                "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = rightNow.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = rightNow.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // Java has Jan = 0
    int dayOfMonth = rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int dayOfWeek = rightNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); // Sun = 1, Sat = 7

    System.out.println("Using as current year: " + year);
    System.out.println("Using as current month: " + month);
    System.out.println("Using as current day of month: " + dayOfMonth);
    System.out.println("Using as current day of week: " + dayOfWeek);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Second Tuesday of next month is " +
                       MONTHABBR[(month+1)%12] + " " +
                       nextServiceDate(year,month,dayOfMonth,dayOfWeek,
                                       3,2)); // 2nd Tuesday(=3) of next month
  }

}
```